# Is there a way to make XDocument Save faster

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to write xml into a file usng XDocument. Previously I was writing to a text file using FileStream and it used to work fast.

Using a Profiler, I found that XDcoument.Save is taking about 90% of the time especially when I am writing large text in the xml node.

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
            XElement root = xDocument.Element("logs");
            root.Add(
                     new XElement(
                         "log",
                         new XElement(
                             "dt",
                             DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")),
                         new XElement(
                             "tm",
                             DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")),
                        new XElement(
                            "st",
                            ConvertStackTrace(stackList)
                            //stackInfo
                            ),
                         new XElement(
                             "t",
                             topic),
                         new XElement(
                             "d",
                             description),                            
                         new XElement(
                             "cu",
                             custom)));
            xDocument.Save(FilePath);
```

Is there another way to write the xml to a file faster than this. Note that the file is about 1MB, and every time it opens the file and adds the node to it.

Comment: A log file will keep getting bigger, probably forgotten about and slow the program down over time. I suggest opening a different log file based on the date, aka `StackLog20151017.xml` for October 17th, 2015. If it is written to a lot, then make it hourly as well. Smaller sizes will save faster.

Comment: Yes I am doing this and have the ability to create a new file based on date or file size. The problem still remain though.

Comment: You ever get a faster save operation with XDocument?

Answer (score 3):

Basically there are three ways how to precess a XML file in .NET

- [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), [XmlTextWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) - the lowest level API for dealing with XML files in .NET. It provides streaming access to the xml data.
- [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) - provides a DOM representation of the XML, that makes it easy to read / modify data
- [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument) - provides a DOM representation of the XML and supports LINQ to XML queries

Both `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` uses `XmlReader` / `XmlWriter` behind the scene. Also both hold all data in memory, so obviously they are slower and more memory intensive. There isn't much you can do about it, because every time you call your code the whole xml document has to be parsed and then dumped to the disk again.

If you switch from `XDocument` to `XmlReader` / `XmlWriter` you can expect a significantly better performance (wild guess 5x-10x faster) but it requires some work as the processing of documents with `XmlReader` / `XmlWriter` isn't as straightforward as with the `XDocument`

Depending on your use case, you can also use some "nasty" tricks like writing only a xml fragment for every log. This way you don't have to parse the document, you can simply append the fragment to the end of the file. The speed would be comparable with using a plain text file. Disadvantage - the produced file isn't valid XML as it hasn't any root element. It is easy to work with such file from your code, but external programs probably wouldn't work.